# Howto create and style 2 Labels within a single Button in JavaFX?

Tags: button, javafx

[image: button]

Have you come across this kind of button? Do you know how to go about creating it?

### Update

Menai just helped me to realize that this Button must have 2 Labels in them. Left Label has black background-color and white text-fill-color while the right Label has silver background-color and red text-fill-color.

I would like to know how to create (with Java or .fxml) and style (CSS) a Button with 2 Labels in it similar to the Button provided as image.

Comment: This is a button or comboBox?

Comment: this is a Button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 2 `Label`s in a `HBox` as graphic for the `Button`. Assign the text color / background color to each label individually:

```xml
<Button styleClass="btn2" stylesheets="@button_style.css" prefWidth="100">
    <graphic>
        <HBox>
            <children>
                <Label HBox.hgrow="NEVER" styleClass="left" text="213"/>
                <Label HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" styleClass="right" text="2x"/>
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </graphic>
</Button>
```

**button_style.css**

```css
.btn2 {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-shadow-highlight-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-inner-border;
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-content-display: graphic-only;
}

.btn2 HBox {
    -fx-fill-height: true;
}

.btn2 .left, .btn2 .right {
    -fx-padding: 4;
}

.btn2 .left {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-background-color: black;
}

.btn2:pressed .left {
    /* use different background for a pressed button */
    -fx-background-color: #555;
}

.btn2 .right {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-body-color;
    -fx-max-width: infinity;
}
```

Comment: wow! Simply astonishing! fabian once again, you have been so helpful all along. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for being you!

Answer (score 0):

You can customize like this button by using CSS

```
.button{
    -fx-background-color:   linear-gradient(to right, black 30%, #cccccc 20%);
    -fx-text-fill:  linear-gradient(to right,white 60%, red 20%);
    -fx-padding: 15

}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Menai, thanks so much for your efforts. As you can see from the image, this Button has 2 Labels in it (1 on left side and 1 on right side). So I have to ask you whether it is possibility to have the right Label having a "black" background-color with the right Label having a silver background.

Comment: Yeah ,you can add an HBox as graphic of button and add two labels.